# Convert long div tag to string?

Tags: javascript, html

Having a long div tag:

```
  <div>
     <style>
    ...
     </style>
    // lots of tags
  </div>
```

is there a quick way of converting it to a string as input for a function:

```
function htmlToElement(html) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

like:

```
"<div>" + 
...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking about, but if you want to know how to write HTML tags/structure in JavaScript file, use template literals ``` `` ```

```js
var html = `
  <div class="bar">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam repellendus, mollitia tempore aperiam ex aspernatur voluptate quo sed quos tempora nisi accusantium rem voluptatem quidem explicabo blanditiis, molestiae necessitatibus illo!</p>
  </div>`;
```

**Template literals (Template strings) - JavaScript | MDN**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

**Here is an example:**

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#foo");
let html = `
    <div class="bar">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam repellendus, mollitia tempore aperiam ex aspernatur voluptate quo sed quos tempora nisi accusantium rem voluptatem quidem explicabo blanditiis, molestiae necessitatibus illo!</p>
  </div>`;
element.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your intention, but you can use outerHTML to grab the `<div>` and it's contents as a string as follows:

```js
var myTemplateHtml = document.getElementById("myTemplate").outerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + myTemplateHtml;
```

```html
<div id="myTemplate">
  <style>
    
  </style>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <span>1</span>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```